# Passing function into tkinter object

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a virtual keyboard using tkinter in python 3.4.

```
class Keyboard(Frame):

def __init__(self, root, callback):
    Frame.__init__(self, root, callback)
    self.pack()
```

callback is going to be a function invoked when user presses a key.
So I will run it like:

```
def press(key):
    print(key)

root = Tk()
keyb = Keyboard(root, press)
keyb.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

However, this must not be the right way to pass the function press into Keyboard because I get an error `"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'items'"`
So how do I pass this function into Keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't mix `pack` and `grid`. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Second, the Frame class does not take a `callback` parameter, but in your code you called it with one:

```
Frame.__init__(self, root, callback)
```

See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm#reference for correct usage.

What you're looking for would be like this, where `callback` was removed completely from `Keyboard`:

```
def press(key):
    print(key)

root = Tk()
keyb = Keyboard(root)
keyb.bind("<Key>", key)
```

Comment: I may have made this confusing with the naming conventions. the callback argument in __init__ is actually the press function I am passing into Keyboard. Should it not be an argument in __init__?

Comment: No, it should not. Looking at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm#reference I don't see a callback argument listed for the Frame class. But it was called in your code with that parameter: `Frame.__init__(self, root, callback)`.

Comment: So then how do I pass the press function into my class?

Comment: Updated the answer to show how you can use `press` to capture a keypress. If you want to pass it into the `Keyboard` class you can, but it shouldn't get passed to the `Frame.__init__`.

Comment: I'm not trying to capture a key press... I literally just want to be able to use that function in my Keyboard class. I know I could just create a method inside Keyboard that does the same thing, but in my case I need to pass the function into the class (don't ask why).

Comment: You can pass the function into the Keyboard class. Just don't pass it to `Frame.__init__`.